# Powershell Get-TfsWorkspace not finding workspace created as another user. (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am having trouble retrieving a workspace from TFS that was created by another user. The workspace location is local and permission set as a public workspace.

I use a known mapped folder to find my workspace (In all cases I will only have one workspace on the machine)

```
$w = Get-TfsWorkspace -Path "C:\LocalRepo\Path_That_I_Know_Is_Mapped"
```

This works when I run the PowerShell script under my own user (Where I have logged into Visual Studio before). However, when I run this as a new user, who has not opened Visual Studio and set the Workspace, it obviously does not find it. I need to do this since I would like to automate this through Ansible, which will run under an administrator account, without wanting to log in everywhere first.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use some parameter to achieve this:

```
$WorkSpace = Get-TfsWorkspace -Server $tfs -Owner $Owner -Name $Workspacename
```

Try to directly specify the owner of workspace.

If you still not able to query any info. Make sure that user you are using to run the powershell, have enough permission to your workspace.

To run the cmdlet, you must have the Read permission set to Allow. In other words, you should make sure that administrator account is able to access your TFS workspace.